# Appropriate journal for an article on practical mathematical teaching

Tags: publishing, journals

I have recently finished working on an article on a subject that falls into the category of "practical mathematical (undergraduate) teaching" -- a set of concrete propositions and examples on a specific issue, that enlighten and help with the teaching of this issue. An example of an article as such can be found [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739X.2016.1153737).

Now, when I try to publish this article, I can not find the appropriate platform. Most journals on mathematical teaching/education look for more theoretical papers, so they decline my paper; on the other hand, this paper does not contain a breakthrough in mathematics, so I can not submit it to "classical" journals.

So I am looking for a journal that on one hand deals with mathematical teaching, but on the other can accept a paper with practical subjects. Would realy appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: Maybe 'The College Mathematics Journal' published by the MAA is appropriate.

Comment: A well-written, lucid presentation and educational content has a potential at the American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: ... or the Notices of the AMS, or the Mathematical Intelligencer, or SIAM Review's Education section.

Comment: I wrote an article on how I went about solving a math problem. (I didn't do anything new, but I wrote about what I learned in the process.) My article is published online (only) in the Journal of Humanistic Mathematics. If your article is particularly interesting, you might check there.

Comment: What is the age group of the students?  Pre-school?  College?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** See also the PDF linked [here](https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Journal-for-Research-in-Mathematics-Education/2017/Vol48/Issue4/Journal-Quality-in-Mathematics-Education/):

[image]

---

Wikipedia has a [list of mathematics education journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_education_journals); I happen to prefer the list of mathematics education journals compiled [here](https://mathedjournals.wikispaces.com/), as they are provided along with some basic facts: journal summary, type of articles solicited, audience reached, etc. Some of these facts derive from the following article:

> Törner, G., & Arzarello, F. (2012). Grading mathematics education research journals. *Editorial: Reminiszenzen*, pp. 31-34. [Link](http://www.didaktik-der-mathematik.de/pdf/gdm-mitteilungen-95.pdf#page=31) (no pay wall).

The second link includes journals that are of generally higher repute in the field of mathematics education. So, for example, although the journal you mention in the OP can be found at the first link (without its own wikipage) and is graded with a B in the Törner and Arzarello article, it is *missing* from the second link; so, I might be hesitant about targeting it as a destination for publishing. I know that it has published a couple of [questionable articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/76653) in the past.

My advice would be to look through recent issues of some of the journals linked to above (assuming you can access them, e.g., at a library or an academic institution), and see where you can find pieces that resemble the sort of paper you would like to write. You may also wish to look at where/if they were cited later on, or at the relevant journal's impact factor/circulation.

One example of a journal that is practice-oriented is NCTM's *Mathematics Teacher*, which includes a section specifically around mathematical findings called **Delving Deeper**. A description of the journal can be found in the second link above (click through for larger print, or check link):

[image]

The appropriate destination will depend on the level of the mathematics discussed (both in content and in the language that you use) as well as your ability to ensure that it is not *just* mathematical findings of too low a caliber to include in a journal of mathematics, but rather that it is connected to "practical mathematical teaching" in a manner that you can describe, justify, and link to the literature on mathematics education.

Comment: FYI the Wikispaces link is broken now!