# What are the leading journals in mathematics education?

Tags: journals

Are there any studies that list the leading (English-language) mathematics education journals?  Here, "leading" could mean something based on data (for example, citations) or something based on opinions (for example, surveys).

Comment: (I believe that this question is not opinion-based because it is asking for studies that provide such a list.)

Answer (score 8):

Geiger, Delzoppo, and Straesser ([2022, p. 551](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10649-022-10174-0)) use the following list (which seems to be unordered):

- The Journal of Mathematics Teacher Education
- For the Learning of Mathematics
- ZDM Mathematics Education
- The Journal of Mathematical Behavior
- Educational Studies in Mathematics
- The Journal for Research in Mathematics Education
- Mathematical Thinking and Learning

This is based on "the ranked journal lists developed by Williams and Leatham ([2017](https://doi.org/10.5951/jresematheduc.48.4.0369)). These lists were based on two sub-studies---one citation-based and the other in-field opinion-based, that produced ranked lists of 20 English language journals that publish Mathematics Education research."

---

<sup>Geiger, V., Delzoppo, C., & Straesser, R. (2022). Supporting English non‑dominant language authors’ efforts to publish: Perspectives from the editors‑in‑chief of highly recognised journals in Mathematics Education. *Educational Studies in Mathematics*, *111*:543–565.</sup>

<sup>Williams, S., & Leatham, K. (2017). Journal quality in mathematics education. *Journal for Research in Mathematics Education*, *48*(4), 369–396.</sup>

Comment: These seven journals seem to be the top ranked ones in the Williams–Leatham study.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, thanks for the info!

Comment: See also this answer: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/11729/77

Comment: Here's a link to a pdf copy of the Williams and Leatham paper: https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Journal-for-Research-in-Mathematics-Education/2017/Vol48/Issue4/jrme2017-07-369/